# How to change a Button layout to its default layout on Android using Java

Tags: java, android

[want to change back the layout from blue to the default layout using code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ql8zl.png)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the reset button is what you want to use to do this:

```
  reset-button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
     @Override
     public void onClick(View v) {
        Intent intent = getIntent();
        finish();
        startActivity(intent);
     }
```

Comment: That's exactly what I've been looking for. It's working, Thank you so much!